# How should we handle announcements?

Tags: discussion

So I see a [post from shirlock](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6634/home-improvement-se-featured-on-weekly-podcast-tuesday-may-31st-at-4pm-will-you) on the podcast that he'll be doing, and I'm looking forward to listening in on this.  But it raises a question, how should we be handling announcements like this since they don't fit the Q&A model?  Do we need a tag for these (blog/announcements)?  SO has their blog, do we have an option to create one on DIY?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Announcements like this should be made here on Meta. A moderator can tag it as [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) so will get highlighted on the main site.

So anybody with something to announce should just post it and then flag their post for moderator attention asking for it to be tagged.

Something else has just occurred to me. If it's deemed important enough then the mods can put a system message up for 48 hours. Not sure this case is important enough though.

BTW: I've flagged Shirlock's post for migration to meta.